# Ethernet sniffer not capturing everything, with tcpdump in parallel it does

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

I wrote a ethernet sniffer in python. It basically opens a socket, sets it to promiscuous mode and then parses every incoming packet, e.g.:

```
import fcntl
import socket

IF = "eth0"
ETH_P_ALL = socket.htons(0x0003)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ALL)

ifr = ifreq()
ifr.ifr_ifrn = IF.encode()

# Get flags
fcntl.ioctl(s, 0x8913, ifr)

# Add promiscuous
ifr.ifr_flags |= 0x100

# Set flags
fcntl.ioctl(s, 0x8914, ifr)

while True:
    pkt_raw, sa_ll = s.recvfrom(65535)
    parse_packet(pkt_raw)
```

Alongside this, I have a measuring function which counts the number of incoming packets per second. To generate packets, I configured a switch such that it forwards all packets to the interface (port mirroring). That is, the incoming packets are not specific for this machine.

Given this setup, I can see rates of around 250 packets/sec. However, if I also run `tcpdump -n -i eth0` in parallel, the rate suddenly goes up to roughly 5000 packets/sec. Interestingly, this only happens if I run `tcpdump` in foreground, e.g. `tcpdump -n -i eth0 > foo` does not change the rate of incoming packets.

Question is: what does tcpdump different when ran in foreground so that the rate of packages is much higher and how to enable this behaviour in the python sniffer?

Comment: do you have privileges? you don't check the return value of the ioctl

Comment: Yes, I run this as root. Return value of `ioctl` is 0.

Comment: Run a `strace` on tcpdump to see what else it does.

Comment: Good point. The only difference I can spot is the `recvfrom` and there most specifically the flags. Reference: `recvfrom(3, [...], 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 66`. Python: `recvfrom(3, [...], 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x800, if3, pkttype=PACKET_OTHERHOST, addr(6)={1, 000ec6c9be94}, [18]) = 66`. Plus there is additionally also a `ioctl(3, SIOCGIFNAME, {ifr_index=3, ifr_name="eth1"}) = 0` after every `recvfrom` in Python. So, where are the additional flags from and what is this additional `ioctl` doing there?

Comment: Interestingly, the socket is also opened bit differently. Python adds `SOCK_CLOEXEC`: `socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 8) = 3`.

Comment: Actually it turns out, that the packet rate increases, whenever there is something printing heavily on the screen. Feeling a bit stupid now, but what the heck is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a homemade mistake. Since the sniffer is working on a server whose traffic is also mirrored, the packet rate always goes up when there is action on the terminal via SSH.